# No se crea el package-lock.json al querer crear una app con npx create-react-app y tira error

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, reactjs, ubuntu

Los comandos que usé son los siguientes, luego de seleccionar una carpeta vacia: npx create-react-app esto me devuelve (pareceria que se ejecuta bien):

```
Creating a new React app in /home/maia/Documentos/Proyectos/React-Mircha/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 7 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.1.2
├─ react-dom@17.0.2
├─ react-scripts@4.0.3
└─ react@17.0.2
info All dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.1.2
├─ immer@8.0.1
├─ react-dev-utils@11.0.4
├─ react-dom@17.0.2
├─ react-scripts@4.0.3
├─ react@17.0.2
└─ scheduler@0.20.2
Done in 28.29s.

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using yarnpkg...
yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 17 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ @testing-library/jest-dom@5.12.0
├─ @testing-library/react@11.2.6
├─ @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3
├─ react-dom@17.0.2
├─ react@17.0.2
└─ web-vitals@1.1.1
info All dependencies
├─ @testing-library/dom@7.30.4
├─ @testing-library/jest-dom@5.12.0
├─ @testing-library/react@11.2.6
├─ @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3
├─ @types/aria-query@4.2.1
├─ @types/jest@26.0.23
├─ @types/testing-library__jest-dom@5.9.5
├─ css.escape@1.5.1
├─ css@3.0.0
├─ dom-accessibility-api@0.5.4
├─ lz-string@1.4.4
├─ min-indent@1.0.1
├─ react-dom@17.0.2
├─ react@17.0.2
├─ redent@3.0.0
├─ strip-indent@3.0.0
└─ web-vitals@1.1.1
Done in 7.43s.
Removing template package using yarnpkg...

yarn remove v1.22.5
[1/2] Removing module cra-template...
[2/2] Regenerating lockfile and installing missing dependencies...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
success Uninstalled packages.
Done in 5.19s.
```

Created git commit.

Success! Created my-app at /home/maia/Documentos/Proyectos/React-Mircha/my-app
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

yarn start
Starts the development server.

yarn build
Bundles the app into static files for production.

yarn test
Starts the test runner.

yarn eject
Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

cd my-app
yarn start

Happy hacking!

**PERO.... al darle npm start, aquí ocurre el error :( (en las carpetas que me devuelve el anterior comando falta la de package-lock.json**

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/maia/Documentos/Proyectos/React-Mircha/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/maia/Documentos/Proyectos/React-Mircha/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/maia/.npm/_logs/2021-05-01T18_34_12_113Z-debug.log
```

Ya eliminé node y lo descargué de nuevo y probé varias cosas pero no encuentro cómo solucionar este error. No entiendo por qué me dice "no such file or directory"
.
.
.
¡¡¡Cualquier ayuda super agradecida!!!

Comment: Si tienes el package.json generado, elimina la carpeta node_modules, y si existe algun package-lock.json eliminalo, podrian estar corruptos estos archivos, despues has un: **npm install**, en la terminar

Comment: Si, funciono, pero no entiendo por que me ocurre eso. Repeti los mismos pasos en otra carpeta nueva, y me ocurre exactamente lo mismo, no se crea el package lock json, tendre que hacer esto en cada proyecto?, no se si le faltara alguna configuracion a mi terminal de linux, ya no se...

Comment: Que linux utilizas, que terminal, tal vez es la de algun editor de texto como vs code? que te sale cuando das al **npm -v** y al **node -v** ?

Comment: Has intentado reinstalar la heramienta create-react-app globalmente, (-g) pero con **sudo** ?

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es porqué todo el proceso de instalación usa `yarn` pero tú usas `npm` para iniciar el proyecto. Digo, a final de cuentas usan en mismo package.json pero a lo mejor podría ser parte del problema.

Comment: @Jamt0 cuando doy npm -v me dice 7.11.2, que es la version, y node -v me devuelve v14.16.1, no instale de forma global porque lei en muchos lugares que no es recomendado instalar globalmente y tampoco con sudo

Comment: @ricardo-dlc hola! que seria yarn? estoy siguiendo este video de Jon MIrcha para usar react por primera vez https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rqT8OP-yn0&list=PLvq-jIkSeTUZ5XcUw8fJPTBKEHEKPMTKk&index=3  y recientemente me pase a Linux, no se si falta configurar algo mas en la terminal

Comment: @Maia, hasta que tengas un conocimiento mas avanzado de npm y linux te recomiedo desintalar **create-react-app**  globalmente, y por lo tanto te pedira **sudo**, estoy casi seguro que eso solucionaria tu problema. No te puedo decir la solucion si no la quieres instalar globalmente, porque hasta aqui llegan mis conocimientos.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc, tienes razon, no lo habia notado, yarn, es otro manejador de paquetes, por lo que si usas yarn, debes hacer yarn add, y despues yarn start, no puedes combinar yarn y npm ya que generara conflicto.

Comment: @Jamt0 tendrìa que hacer algo como la primera respuesta de esta pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451813/issues-with-uninstalling-create-react-app disculpa tantas consultas, es que he instalado / desinstalado npm, react, node, tantas veces que ya estoy un poco perdida, gracias <3

Comment: Diria que sigas esos pasos, a ver que puede pasar, y tranqui, estamos para ayudar

Comment: @Maia también sería bueno que mostraras la estructura de archivos creada por npm/yarn según sea el caso. Pero lo que te comentan es cierto, no puedes combinar npm y yarn pues puede traer problemas. Respondiendo a tu pregunta, ambos son manejadores de paquetes siendo npm el más utilizado, ambos se basan en package.json para la instalación de paquetes, en principio yarn solucionaba ciertos desperfectos de seguridad y rendimiento que tenía npm, lo cierto es que ahora están a la par y depende más de gustos.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc gracias Ricardo por tu respuesta! Lo que hice ahora es borrar yarn, y volver a instalar nvm y ahora SÌ me instala todos los paquetes al enviar "npx create-react-app proyecto" (que serìan estos: node_modules, public, src, package.json, package-lock.json, readme.md) PERO cuando pongo "npm start" me da: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/maia/Documentos/Proyectos/Test2/package.json' 
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.....   :( :( por lo menos pude eliminar yarn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer tu proceso de instalación usa [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), por lo que para iniciar tu app, despues de ser creada tendrias que utilizar

```
yarn start
```

yarn y npm ambos son gestores de dependencias de javascript, pero si usas yarn para instalar debes utilizar yarn para start el proyecto.

La manera de hacer que no instale por yarn que conozco es desintalando la herramienta, de espe moto se instala por npm y se puede hacer:

```
npm start
```

Ademas se debe tener insalada la dependencia create-ract-app globarmente,
en linux:

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

Comment: Despues de usar el comando npx create-react-app probando (en una carpeta nueva) y luego yarn start, me tira el siguiente error: error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/maia/Documentos/Proyectos/Test-yar"   ... con lo cual lo que me queda por hacer seria desinstalar yarn?

Comment: podrias intentar desinstalar yarn, asi el create-ract-app utilizaria npm, no se exactamnete a que se debe este comportamiento

Comment: lo que hice ahora es borrar yarn, y volver a instalar nvm y ahora SÌ me instala todos los paquetes al enviar "npx create-react-app proyecto" (que serìan estos: node_modules, public, src, package.json, package-lock.json, readme.md) PERO cuando pongo "npm start" me da: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/maia/Documentos/Proyectos/Test2/package.json' npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file..... :( :( por lo menos pude eliminar yarn

Comment: instalaste create-react-app globalmente y con sudo?

Comment: ahora SÌIIIIIIII, hace 2 dias que estoy con esto, no se como agradecerte jajaja gracias en todos los idiomas por la paciencia <3 <3 <3 <3

Comment: Dale, perfecto, me puedes agradecer dandome puntuación positiva, y dando la respuesta como solucion jejeje